# BigQuery @run_date used as different types

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a scheduled query using the `@run_date` parameter in BigQuery.

```
SELECT
  @run_date AS run_date,
  timestamp,
  event
FROM
  `ops-data.usage.full_user_dataset`
WHERE
  DATE(timestamp) < @run_date
```

`timestamp` is of type `TIMESTAMP`

I am unable to schedule it - the schedule option is greyed out in the new UI and unavailable in the classic UI (it says it requires valid SQL). If I try and run the query then I receive error message `Undeclared parameter 'run_date' is used assuming different types (DATE vs INT64) at [2:3]`

After trying various things I was able to schedule the query below. The idea was to force BigQuery to treat @run_date as a date without changing it

```
SELECT
  DATE_SUB(@run_date, INTERVAL 0 DAY) AS run_date,
  timestamp,
  event
FROM
  `ops-data.usage.full_user_dataset`
WHERE
  DATE(timestamp) < @run_date
```

Why does this error occur and why does the fix work?

Comment: Probably `@run_date` as a query parameter can't hold `DATE` type value itself, but needs to be subtracted from expression and `DATE_SUB` is a valid options to do it here.

Comment: The same error occurs when you replace `@run_date` with `@run_time` so I don't think it has to do with the specific query parameter.  @jweob have you tried scheduling the first query using the CLI with `bq mk` and does it work? I'm guessing this is something Console UI related since parametrized queries are not supported in the UI.

Comment: A bug has been created here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148921951

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a bug around `@run_date`, below workaround should work for you until it is fixed.

```sql
DECLARE run_date DATE DEFAULT @run_date;

SELECT
  run_date,
  timestamp,
  event
FROM
  `ops-data.usage.full_user_dataset`
WHERE
  DATE(timestamp) < run_date
```

BTW, since the workaround utilizes Scripting and not being able to set a destination table, if you do need a destination table, it has to be written as:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE <yourDestinationTable>
AS SELECT ... -- your query
```